# OS Xでuchar.hが見つからない

Tags: macos, c, clang

OS X 10.11で`#include <uchar.h>`と書いてコンパイルすると`fatal error: 'uchar.h' file not found`となってしまいます
なぜでしょうか?

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: uchar.hはC11で追加されたヘッダーファイルですが、Clang/LLVMにはC標準ライブラリは含まれていないので、別途C11対応のC標準ライブラリが必要です。OSに含まれているのかXcodeに含まれるものなのかは知りませんが、どこかにuchar.hは存在しますか？（ちなみに、[オープンソース版のOS X 10.11.2のLibc](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1082.20.4/)には含まれていません。）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uchar.hはC11規格に含まれているのですが、clangはC11を
[部分的にサポートしている](http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/c/c11#Compiler_support)状態のようです。

Comment: その記事は[2013年12月に書かれた古い記事](https://en.wikichip.org/w/index.php?title=c%2Fc11&type=revision&diff=796&oldid=592)です。また、Clang/LLVMにはC標準ライブラリは含まれていません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。勉強になります。

Answer (score 3):

Clangが対応していないのではなく、OS XのCライブラリ(/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)がuchar.hが提供するライブラリに対応しておらず、OS X自身にヘッダファイルが用意されていないからです。これはClangだけでなくGCCでも同じです。HomeBrewでいれたGCC 6.2でも同じくエラーになります(macOS 10.12で確認)。

GCCの資料になりますが、uchar.hについてはライブラリの問題となっています。

[C11Status - GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status)

最新のLinuxで2.16以上のglibcを採用しているのであれば、ClangでもGCCでもコンパイルは可能です。逆に言うと2.16未満のglibcを使った古いLinuxではGCCやClangをいくら最新にしても、OS Xと同じくコンパイルはできません。OS XについてはglibcではなくlibSystem.B.dylibというのを使っていますが、macOS 10.12でも対応していないようですので、いつ対応するのかは不明です。